# Not mentioning of sm behaviour

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I found the following snippet in the official bootstrap website. I would like to know how it behaves for tablets.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-8</div>
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

In the above snippet, xs-12 will take one full row and xs-6 will occupy half of next row. Similarly md seems to have 8 parts and 4 parts out of 12. But sm is mentioned only for 6? What about the remaining 6. How it will behave? Will the second div occupy the next half in the row inheriting sm-6?

Comment: Resize your browser and find out.

Comment: sm-6 occupies full in tablet size, I don't understand why!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}
.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 red">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-8</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 green">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Second div will get its width because of `col-xs-12` and will fall in next line